# GraphQL : must be Output Type but got: undefined Error

Tags: mysql, node.js, graphql, isodate

I was trying to fetch a MySQL Date from database and output it with graphql. My application builds and runs without any issue. But in graphql ui, it says below error.

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "The type of Tour.arrival_date must be Output Type but got: undefined."
    }
  ]
}
```

My type.js file looks like this.

```
let {
    GraphQLID,
    GraphQLString,
    GraphQLInt,
    GraphQLFloat,
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLNonNull,
    GraphQLDate,
    GraphQLList
} = require('graphql')




// Defines the type
module.exports = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Tour',
    description: 'A Tour',
    fields: {
        id: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)
        },
        name: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
        },
        pax_count: {
            type: GraphQLInt
        },
        arrival_date: {
            type: GraphQLDate
        }

    }
})
```

I am using below library for ISO Date.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-iso-date

Can someone please advice me what could be the possible issue on this?
Please note that I'm really new to GraphQL.

Thanks
Buddhika

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing `GraphQLDate` from `graphql`, but `graphql` does not export a variable with that name because there is no built-in scalar for Date in GraphQL.js. If you're using `graphql-iso-date`, then import the appropriate scalar as described in the documentation:

```
const { GraphQLDate } = require('graphql-iso-date')
```

Comment: Hi @daniel-rearden Thanks a lot. This resolved the problem.